# Flask routing problem in my app: bad request 400

Tags: python, html, css, mysql, flask

Here i am route towards the details of the customer who wishes to buy some stuff he have to fill the fields in order to purchase some products.
but when i route to the link the below error is popping up
I am getting this error when i route to the details i am getting the error as mentioned below how to resolve this
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError:
400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'email'

```
details.html this is a html file
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Details</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/landing_page.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/login.css')}}">
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <center>    
        <h2>Personal Details</h2>
        <div class="details">
            <input type ="text" name ="fname" placeholder="Name" pattern="[A-Za-z]{,3}" title="Enter valid name" required> 
            <br/>
            <input type ="text" name ="email" placeholder="E-mail id"  data-type = "E-mail" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" title = "Enter a valid email" required> 
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="phonenumber" placeholder="Phone number" title="Enter your mobile number without +91" pattern="[0-9]{10,10}" required="required">
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="Altphonenumber" placeholder="Alternative Phone number" title="Enter your mobile number without +91" pattern="[0-9]{10,10}" required="required">
            <br/>
            <input type ="text" name ="address" placeholder="Address"  pattern="[a-z0-9#,]{7,}$" title = "Enter a valid Address" required> 
            <br/>
            <button class = "btn btn2" type="submit" name="Create">Proceed</button>
        </div>
        </center>
    </form>
    <br>
    <footer class="container">
        <center>
          <div>Designed and Developed by Sharath S Hebbar</div>
        </center>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
    
app.py is a server written in flask

#details
@app.route('/details', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def details():
    if not(c_id == 0) and request.method == "POST":
        data = request.form
        #Name = data['fname']
        Email = data['email']
        Phone = data['phonenumber']
        Altphone = data['Altphonenumber']
        Address = data['address']
       
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO details(name,email,phone,alt_phone,address) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (Name,Email,Phone,Altphone,Address))

        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
        return render_template('creditcarddetails.html')
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('details.html')
```

Comment: I think this keyerror could only occur when email is not in request.form? Your code is running fine here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to mention the `action` attribute in `form`.
In your case it will be  `action="{{ url_for('details') }}"` 
and instead of storing it in request.form in data variable you can directly put it in this way:
`Email = request.form['email']`